# Using Spring Security extras with Spring Boot in JavaFX application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, javafx

I am writing a small application using the stack Spring Boot + Spring Security + JavaFX.
For Integration JavaFX with Spring Boot & Spring Security I used this source from Github:
https://github.com/emorgado/javafx-springboot-springsecurity

How can I use Spring Security extras (like extras for Thymeleaf) in FXML files?
For example:
Thymeleaf -

```
<li class="nav-item" sec:authorize="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')">
  <a class="nav-link" th:href="@{/settings}">
     <p>Settings</p>
  </a>
</li>
```

FXML -

```
<Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Settings">
    <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#mainSettingsAction" text="Main settings" />
</Menu>
```

Is there any way to use attributes like sec:authorize or tags `<security>` in FXML file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many thanks to Charles Lee for help!
I provide my solution to this problem:

```
@FXML private MenuItem settingsMenu;
    @FXML
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    Doctor currentUser = (Doctor) doctorService.findDoctorByDoctorUsername(authentication.getName());

    if(!currentUser.getRoles().contains(Role.ADMIN)) {
    settingsMenu.getParentMenu().getItems().remove(settingsMenu);
    }

    }
```

Comment: Sure. I just gave a hint. Of course, "ROLE_ADMIN" should not be hardcoded.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should make your own fxml compiler like e(fx)clipse FXML compiler.

but,
You can use this trick.

in .fxml

```
<MenuItem fx:id="menuSettings" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#mainSettingsAction" text="Main settings" userData="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
```

in the controller.

```
@FXML private MenuItem menuSettings;

if(menuSettings != null && menuSettings.getUserData() != null) {
    if("ROLE_ADMIN".equals(menuSettings.getUserData().toString())) {
        menuSettings.getParentMenu().getItems().remove(menuSettings);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I tried what you propose to do, but it doesn’t work correctly.   
I used logger to get current User Role - log.info(settingsMenu.getUserData());  It returns ROLE_ADMIN when I authorize with admin privileges or just user privileges. So your code delete menuSettings for both users (for admin & for user)

Comment: May be I need to get current user Role from autowired AuthenticationManager. And then check if current user roleList contains ROLE_ADMIN ?